# UPSERT multiple rows, do ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET conditional check/update row-wise

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-performance, bulk-insert, upsert

I'm trying to `UPSERT` multiple rows into a Postgres table (ie. `INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET` multiple rows).

But I want the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET` conditional check/update do be done **row-wise** (ie. per-row).

Eg. there's a table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t00;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t00(
  userid int8  PRIMARY KEY,
  col00  int8  DEFAULT 0,
  col01  int8  DEFAULT 0
);
```

such that I want to update `col01` conditionally based on the value of `col00`.

So you `INSERT` rows and update 1 row:

```
INSERT  INTO t00 (userid)  VALUES (0),(1);
UPDATE t00  SET col00=1  WHERE userid=0;
```

And now comes the problem.

What I want is something like the following (invalid Postgres, I checked):

```
INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,col00,col01)
  VALUES (0,1,2) ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE SET col00=EXCLUDED.col00, col01=EXCLUDED.col01  WHERE t00.col00!=EXCLUDED.col00,
  VALUES (1,1,2) ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE SET col00=EXCLUDED.col00, col01=EXCLUDED.col01  WHERE t00.col00!=EXCLUDED.col00;
```

or (also invalid Postgres, I checked):

```
INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,col00,col01)  VALUES
  (0,1,2) ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE SET col00=EXCLUDED.col00, col01=EXCLUDED.col01  WHERE t00.col00!=EXCLUDED.col00,
  (1,1,2) ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE SET col00=EXCLUDED.col00, col01=EXCLUDED.col01  WHERE t00.col00!=EXCLUDED.col00;
```

So I'm only left with the following:

```
INSERT  INTO t00 (userid,col00,col01)  VALUES
  (0,1,2),
  (1,1,2) ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO UPDATE SET col00=EXCLUDED.col00, col01=EXCLUDED.col01  WHERE t00.col00!=EXCLUDED.col00;
```

The desired result (after the upsert) is that:

0. `userid=0` has: `col00=1` and `col01=0`
1. `userid=1` has: `col00=1` and `col01=2`

The (undesired) result is that:

0. `userid=0` has `col00=1` and `col01=2`
1. `userid=1` has `col00=1` and `col01=2`

So, what I want is a fine-grained "row-by-row" independent upsert, not an "all-or-nothing" upsert over ALL rows.

I'm already doing what I want with a for-loop (by doing 1 separate Postgres call for each row upsert, which is ugly), but I wonder if the last call I proposed is guaranteed to do what I want? (It does in this case, at least.)

(I also wonder if it's higher-performing that doing multiple separate Postgres calls for millions of rows.)

Comment: This [Medium article](https://anuradha-15.medium.com/update-insert-upsert-multiple-records-in-different-db-types-63aa44191884) may have your answer.  It appears you need to remove the WHERE clause.